# Huge space inbetween the top of the page and the navbar

Tags: html, css

Okay so as you can see here: http://wouldyoureally.freeiz.com/ The space inbetween the top of the page and the navbar is huge and I don't know why, i've listed the CSS and HTML if anyone could help me that'd be great thanks!

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<center>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="description" content="Would You Really?"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="CyberBullying, WebRangersNZ"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylex.css'/>


<div id='cssmenu'>
<p align="right">
          <ul class="navbar">
             <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="about.html">The Victim</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="who.html">Where You Can Get Help</a></li>
                   <li><a href="what.html">Who You Can Talk To</a></li>
                   <li><a href="why.html"></a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="mission.html">The Bully</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="problem.html">The Consequences</a></li>
                   <li><a href="plan.html">Who You Can Talk To</a></li>
                   <li><a href="solution.html">Where You Can Get Help</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="whatit.html">What It Is</a>
                <ul>               
                   <li><a href="where.html">Where It Is Done</a></li>
                   <li><a href="whodoes.html">Who Does It</a></li>
                   <li><a href="how.html">How It Can Be Stopped</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="email.html">Email Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="chat.html">Chat With Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="message.html">Send Us a Message</a></li>
                </ul>        
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Support Us</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="facebook.html">Like Us On Facebook</a></li>
                   <li><a href="twitter.html">Follow Us On Twitter</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">ThunderClap</a></li>
                   <li><a href="sponsorus.html">Sponsor Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="donate.html">Donate To Us</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
             <li><a href="oursponsor.html">Our Sponsors</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">N/A</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">N/A</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">N/A</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">N/A</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>
</div>
</p>
</center>
```

---

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);

#wrap   {
    width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
#cssmenu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}   

#cssmenu    {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
    border-right: 0px solid #FFFFFF; 
    }

#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #CECECE;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .27s;
  -moz-transition: color .27s;
  -ms-transition: color .27s;
  -o-transition: color .27s;
  transition: color .27s;
  }
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #1166CC;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #0066CC;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #0066CC;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #0066CC;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li     {
        height: auto;
        width: 150px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
        float: left;  /* This lines up the menu items horizontally */
        text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
        list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
        font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Comic Sans MS;  
        padding: 7px 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
                        }

#cssmenu li:hover, a:hover {background-color: #FFFFFF;} 

#cssmenu li ul  {
        display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
        height: auto;                                   
        margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
        padding: 7px 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */         
        }               

#cssmenu li:hover ul    {
                        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
                        }

 #cssmenu li ul li {background-color: #FFFFFF;} 

 #cssmenu li ul li a    {
        border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
        border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
        border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
        }

#cssmenu li ul li a:hover   {background-color: #FFFFFF;}

#cssmenu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}











#twitterbox

.twitterbox {
    .floatright 
{ 
float: right; 
width: 100px; 

}
```

Comment: any reason for not having a `<head>`, adding all `<style>, <meta>` tags in `<body'>, and using multiple `<script>` blocks..?

Comment: Just been forgetting things. Failing heavily. xD
Also I think the script blocks are from when I was trying to add a facebook button.

Comment: Please structure the code and update the question, if possible provide and online link or something like a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue..

Comment: I've done what you've asked and there is a link to a test server showing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to validate your HTML. In this case your biggest problem is that you are trying to nest a `<ul>` inside a `<p>` inside an `<h1>`.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this answer. :) - Looking back at old questions it seems so obvious now! But 8 years of learning would do that. XD

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your browser is not applying some default padding or margin to the body of your document ?

Add the following CSS rules to remove the potential padding and margin of the body :

> body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS settings on a website without body{ defined is:

```
body {display: block; margin: 8px;}
```

You should define the body{ into your css if you want to get rid of the standard body class.

```
body {margin: 0px;}
```